# C the same global variable defined in different files

Tags: c, linker, one-definition-rule

I am reading [this code from here](http://coolshell.cn/articles/10115.html#more-10115)(in Chinese). There is one piece of code about testing global variable in C. The variable `a` has been defined in the file `t.h` which has been included twice. In file `foo.c` defined a `struct b` with some value and a `main` function. In `main.c` file, defined two variables without initialized.

```
/* t.h */
#ifndef _H_
#define _H_
int a;
#endif

/* foo.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "t.h"

struct {
   char a;
   int b;
} b = { 2, 4 };

int main();

void foo()
{
    printf("foo:\t(&a)=0x%08x\n\t(&b)=0x%08x\n
        \tsizeof(b)=%d\n\tb.a=%d\n\tb.b=%d\n\tmain:0x%08x\n",
        &a, &b, sizeof b, b.a, b.b, main);
}

/* main.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "t.h"

int b;
int c;

int main()
{
    foo();
    printf("main:\t(&a)=0x%08x\n\t(&b)=0x%08x\n
        \t(&c)=0x%08x\n\tsize(b)=%d\n\tb=%d\n\tc=%d\n",
        &a, &b, &c, sizeof b, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

After using Ubuntu GCC 4.4.3 compiling, the result is like this below:

```
foo:    (&a)=0x0804a024
    (&b)=0x0804a014
    sizeof(b)=8
    b.a=2
    b.b=4
    main:0x080483e4
main:   (&a)=0x0804a024
    (&b)=0x0804a014
    (&c)=0x0804a028
    size(b)=4
    b=2
    c=0
```

Variable `a` and `b` has the same address in two function, but the size of `b` has changed. I can't understand how it worked!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Use `%p` for printing pointers, also you should add `foo` to your header.

Comment: If you want to resolve the conflict, declare the var static.

Comment: It's from [coolshell](http://coolshell.cn/articles/10115.html) (in Chinese), right?

Comment: @YuHao yes, I am reading this from coolshell but can't understand clearly, so I copy his code to here for discussing! Sorry for that! I have added statement at the beginning.

Comment: @liuan No, I'm just curious, that's all. I don't think that's a problem, since you didn't copy the whole article. Personally I don't like what is explained in that article either. So I'm glad to see the problem discussed here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are violating C's "one definition rule", and the result is undefined behavior. The "one definition rule" is not formally stated in the standard as such. We are looking at objects in different source files (aka, translation units), so we concerned with "external definitions". The "one external definition" semantic is spelled out (C11 6.9 p5):

> An *external definition* is an external declaration that is also a definition of a function (other than an inline definition) or an object. If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an expression (other than as part of the operand of a `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator whose result is an integer constant), somewhere in the entire program **there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier**; otherwise, there shall be no more than one.

Which basically means you are only allowed to *define* an object at most **once**. (The otherwise clause allows you to not define an external object at all if it is never used anywhere in the program.)

Note that you have two external definitions for `b`. One is the structure that you initialize in `foo.c`, and the other is the *tentative definition* in `main.c`, (C11 6.9.2 p1-2):

> If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and an initializer, the
>   declaration is an external definition for the identifier.
>
> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier `static`, constitutes a *tentative definition*. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer equal to 0.

So you have multiple definitions of `b`. However, there is another error, in that you have defined `b` with different types. First note that multiple declarations to the same object with external linkage is allowed. However, when the same name is used in two different source files, that name refers to the same object (C11 6.2.2 p2):

> In the set of translation units and libraries that constitutes an entire program, each
>   declaration of a particular identifier with external linkage denotes the same object or
>   function.

C puts a strict limitation on declarations to the same object (C11 6.2.7 p2):

> All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type;
>   otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Since the types for `b` in each of your source files do not actually match, the behavior is undefined. (What constitutes a compatible type is described in detail in all of C11 6.2.7, but it basically boils down to being that the types have to match.)

So you have two failings for `b`:

- Multiple definitions.
- Multiple declarations with incompatible types.

Technically, your declaration of `int a` in both of your source files also violates the "one definition rule". Note that `a` has external linkage (C11 6.2.2 p5):

> If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no storage-class specifier, its linkage is external.

But, from the quote from C11 6.9.2 earlier, those `int a` tentative definitions are external definitions, and you are only allowed one of those from the quote from C11 6.9 at the top.

The usual disclaimers apply for undefined behavior. Anything can happen, and that would include the behavior you observed.

---

A common extension to C is to allow multiple external definitions, and is described in the C standard in the informative Annex J.5 (C11 J.5.11):

> There may be more than one external definition for the identifier of an object, with or
>   without the explicit use of the keyword `extern`; **if the definitions disagree**, or more than one is initialized, **the behavior is undefined** (6.9.2).

(Emphasis is mine.) Since the definitions for `a` agree, there is no harm there, but the definitions for `b` do not agree. This extension explains why your compiler does not complain about the presence of multiple definitions. From the quote of C11 6.2.2, the linker will attempt to reconcile the multiple references to the same object.

Linkers typically use one of two models for reconciling multiple definitions of the same symbol in multiple translation units. These are the "Common Model" and the "Ref/Def Model". In the "Common Model", multiple objects with the same name are folded into a single object in a `union` style manner so that the object takes on the size of the largest definition. In the "Ref/Def Model", each external name must have exactly one definition.

The GNU toolchain uses the "Common Model" by default, and a "Relaxed Ref/Def Model", where it enforces a strictly one definition rule for a single translation unit, but does not complain about violations across multiple translation units.

The "Common Model" can be suppressed in the GNU compiler by using the `-fno-common` option. When I tested this on my system, it caused "Strict Ref/Def Model" behavior for code similar to yours:

```
$ cat a.c
#include <stdio.h>
int a;
struct { char a; int b; } b = { 2, 4 };
void foo () { printf("%zu\n", sizeof(b)); }
$ cat b.c
#include <stdio.h>
extern void foo();
int a, b;
int main () { printf("%zu\n", sizeof(b)); foo(); }
$ gcc -fno-common a.c b.c
/tmp/ccd4fSOL.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `a'
/tmp/ccMoQ72v.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccd4fSOL.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `b'
/tmp/ccMoQ72v.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `b' changed from 8 in /tmp/ccMoQ72v.o to 4 in /tmp/ccd4fSOL.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
$
```

<sub>I personally feel the last warning issued by the linker should always be provided regardless of the resolution model for multiple object definitions, but that is neither here nor there.</sub>

---

**References:**
[Unfortunately, I can't give you the link to my copy of the C11 Standard](http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/The_Standard)
[What are `extern` variables in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1433204/315052)
[The "Beginner's Guide to Linkers"](http://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html)
[SAS Documentation on External Variable Models](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc750/html/clug/zxtrname.htm)

Comment: It's worth noting that two typical implementations are the ones usually called "def/ref model" and "common model".  The latter is what typical Unix/Linux linkers use and gives rise to the observed behavior.  The phrase "common model" appears to refer to Fortran COMMON blocks as implemented on many mainframes in the 1960s.

Comment: @torek: Thanks for prompting me to do a little more research. I've updated the answer.

Comment: The text this answer quotes from C 2011 J.5.11 describes a common extension to the C language. It is not a definitive part of the standard. The part of the C standard that implies the one-definition rule is neither J.5.11, 6.9.2, nor 6.2.2. It is 6.2.7 2: “All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Thanks! I re-read 6.9, and I can't believe I missed it before. It pretty much says "one external definition". I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Formally, it is illegal to define the same variable (or function) with external linkage more than once. So, from the formal point of view the behavior of your program is undefined.

Practically, allowing multiple definitions of the same variable with external linkage is a popular compiler extension (a common extension, mentioned as such in the language specification). However, in order to be used properly, each definition shall declare it with the same type. And no more than one definition shall include initializer.

Your case does not match the common extension description. Your code compiles as a side effect of that common extension, but its behavior is still undefined.

Comment: I had already up voted this answer earlier, but this answer first addressed specifically the common extension that allowed for multiple external definitions.

Answer (score 2):

The piece of code seems to break the one-definition rule on purpose. It will invoke undefined behavior, don't do that.

About the global variable `a`: don't put definition of a global variable in a header file, since it will be included in multiple .c files, and leads to multiple definition. Just put declarations in the header and put the definition in one of the .c files.

In t.h:

```
extern int a;
```

In foo.c

```
int a;
```

About the global variable `b`: don't define it multiple times, use `static` to limit the variable in a file.

In foo.c:

```
static struct {
   char a;
   int b;
} b = { 2, 4 };
```

In main.c

```
static int b;
```

Comment: +1 for specific remedies to avoid one definition rule violations.

Answer (score 1):

`b` has the same address because the **linker** decided to resolve the conflict for you.

`sizeof` shows different values because sizeof is evaluated at **compile time**. At this stage, the compiler only knows about one `b` (the one defined in the current file).

Comment: +1 for knowing it was the linker that put the `b`s in the same memory location.

Answer (score 0):

At the time foo is being compiled, the `b` that is in scope is the two ints vector `{2, 4}` or 8 bytes when an sizeof(int) is 4.
When main is compiled, b has just been redeclared as an `int` so a size of 4 makes sense. Also there is probably "padding bytes" added to the struct after "a" such that the next slot (the int) is aligned on 4 bytes boundary.

Answer (score -1):

a and b have the same addresses because they occur at the same points in the file.  The fact that b is a different size doesn't matter where the variable begins.  If you added a variable c between a and b in one of the files, the address of the bs would differ.