# Overwrite variables while linking c files

Tags: c, linker, double, overwrite

I have two files:

fir.c

```
int x = 7;
int y = 5;
int main()
{
    p2();
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

and also:

sec.c

```
double x;
void p2()
{
    x = 6;
}
```

After linking and compiling these two files, I'm printing `x` and get 0 as output.
Moreover, after printing `y`, I get `4018000` as output.
I understand that `x` overwrites `y`, but why do I get these values​​? What exactly does this mean?

Comment: It means that your program is ill-formed and/or has undefined behaviour. You have defined two global variables with the same name, or the same variable with two different types, depending on how you look at it, but either way it's not allowed.

Comment: It means you're doing something you shouldn't be doing. Just stop it. It doesn't matter _why_ it's doing seemingly weird stuff.

Comment: Interesting. I would expect that linker produces an error about multiple definitions of x, it is not the case however.

Comment: Doesn't your linker complain when you do this ?

Comment: I'm getting a warning, but the code compile.

Comment: A warning you don't fully understand is an error, plain and simple.

Comment: So, why after printing y, I get 4018000 ? what is the meaning?

Comment: @n.m. This is not a question of type. The variable is defined twice and is allocated in two files. My linker (invoked by gcc) does not produce any message. Even not a warning.

Comment: @Marian I've already realized that...

Comment: "what is the meaning" --- there's no meaning. Only valid programs have meaning. This one isn't, and doesn't.

Comment: @Marian This is a GNU ld behaviour which is IMHO just wrong. You can make it emit a warning with `-Wl,--warn-common`.

Comment: @Marian: mine does: /usr/bin/ld: Warning: alignment 4 of symbol `x' in /tmp/ccO8gzp7.o is smaller than 8 in /tmp/ccYz8g80.o

Comment: Actually a good answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800187/c-the-same-global-variable-defined-in-different-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I'm pretty sure you using "%x" and not "%d in your printf. Second, I'm pretty sure it is 40180000 not 4018000 (an extra zero).

Assuming this is true, here's where you are getting this value:

In the first program, x and y are stored in the right next to each other in memory as ints (4 bytes). The second program links to the first program's "x" and treats it as a double (8 bytes), does not allocate new memory for the second program.

Now for the binary representation of "6" in IEEE double precision ([link here](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=054))

0x01000000 00011000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 is stored at "x"

HEX=0x4018000000000000

Since the first program sees only the int portion

0x01000000 00011000 00000000 00000000

=0x40180000

And since "%x" shows you the hex "40180000" is printed.

BTW: Reproduced your outcome just to make sure.