# When is a definition of a global variable in C conditional?

Tags: c, variables, global

If I say

```
int i=8;
```

outside of every function, is this definition of a global variable tentative and why?

EDIT: I changed 'conditional' to *tentative*, I translated it wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by _conditional_?

Comment: Yes.  Existing outside of any other scope / function / namespace / class is the **definition** of a global in every language that has them.

Comment: "Conditional definition"??? Standard C terminology knows no such concept. What do you mean by conditional definition?

Comment: Thing is, I don't know if I translated it right from my language, 'conditional' is the best translation that came to mind. This is a question that was on an exam last year, I did not make it up.

Comment: @Nebeski: C language has a concept of "*tentative* definition". However, definitions that include an initializer are never tentative.

Comment: I think that is it, I didn't get any results from google, because I searched the wrong terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define a global variable as you have illustrated, then any function that is defined before that variable will not be aware of the variable unless some declaration has been made before the function, or within the function.

```
void foo () {
    extern int i; /* declare presence of global i */
    /* code that uses i */
}

int i=8;

void bar () {
    /* code that uses i, does not need declaration */
}
```

A tentative definition for a global is a bare declaration without an initializer.

```
int i; /* tentative definition */

void foo () {
    /* code that uses i */
}
```

The tentative definition allows `i` to be used like in a forward declaration, however, it will also be treated as a default initialized external definition unless an explicit external definition for `i` is found.

Comment: If you would like some gory details, you can view [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17800382/315052).

Comment: The description of tentative definition isn't right; it doesn't "match" a different translation unit. If there is `int i = 5;` in another unit then it is undefined behaviour due to multiple definitions. (your link describes this in more detail)

Comment: @M.M: I was working from memory on how things worked. But yes, I described that technicality in my linked post.

Comment: Your last paragraph is really completely different to how tentative definitions work. It doesn't behave as if there were a default initializer, external declarations don't make any difference (unless they provide an initializer), and it does not hint of definitions in another TU (which would be UB). It always creates a definition at the end if no definition with initializer was given in the current TU.

Comment: @M.M: `int a;` bare has no initializer. If an instance is created, is it not default initialized? If `extern int a;` follows `int a;` does it not treat the tentative as another external declaration? Aren't external declarations hints that definitions are elsewhere?

Comment: `int a; extern int a;` is identical to `int a;` .   External declarations are not necessarily hints that definitions are elsewhere. (`static int x = 5;` is an external declaration - don't mix up "external declaration" with "external linkage").   `int i;` is not default-initialized yet, there may later be `int i = 5;` for example.  The difference is more pronounced in the case of a type that is not completed until later (e.g. `int a[];` differs from `int a[] = { 0 };` in that it is incomplete)

Answer (score 2):

If you declare the variable outside of a function scope, then it has [static storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration) and by default [external linkage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration#Linkage). It means that the variable is accessible everywhere in the current translation unit (i.e. the current C file produced by the pre-processor). The variable is also accessible in other translation units, but you need to either declare it there as `extern int i;` or [tentatively define it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3095861/3093378) as `int i;`. Note that if you define the variable as `static int i = 8;` at file scope, then the variable will have [internal linkage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration#Linkage) and you won't be able to use it in other translation units, even if declaring there as `extern int i;`.

There is no *conditional* going on here, I don't know what you mean by this word.

**EDIT**

No, yours is not a [tentative definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/extern#Tentative_definitions).

Comment: Wrong: "If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage." (6.2.2p4).

Comment: That's not quite right on extern.  Unless you explicitly declare it to be `static` within your translation unit, then the linker will allow *any other* translation unit to access it via an `extern` declaration.  Also, since this guy is clearly a beginner:  "translation unit" = ".c file" in very general terms.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland: To be more precise: A translation unit is each ".c"-file passed to the compiler plus all `#include`d files - directly or indirectly.

Comment: I think vsoftco is using the term `static` in a different sense than the C keyword.  It is being used in its broader, non-C-specific sense of storage duration, not scope.

Comment: @M.M I was talking about the static storage duration, at global scope, see the link.

Comment: @Olaf which part of this answer is wrong? There was no mention of linkage.

Comment: @M.M Ohh I see. I will try to clarify it.

Comment: The semi-informal term "global variable" usually refers to objects with external linkage (and, naturally, static storage duration). File scope objects declared with `static` are not typically referred to as "global".

Comment: If the answer is wrong, please let me know exactly where and why.

Comment: The statement "By default it is visible only in the current translation unit." is  just flat out incorrect.  Globals you declare w/o `static` can be accessed by *any* code linked against yours unless you make them "file scoped", i.e. static linkage.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland How would you access it without using `extern` in the second translation unit? Also I edited the answer before your comment. If there is something wrong with it now, let me know.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland Also, there is no static linkage. There is internal linkage, external linkage and no linkage. However, for the scope of this answer, I don't think OP benefits more if we go deep into standardese, that's why I didn't mention anything about linkage (except when you use `static int i = 8;`, which makes the linkage internal).

Comment: Clearly, you do need `extern` in the second translation unit.  But declaring a symbol as `extern` is not what gives it external linkage. That's the default mode of operation.  You must use `static` to prevent that.  You got me on static vs internal for linkage terminology.  But I think its a very important distinction that C programmers should learn early.   Liberal use of the `static` keyword, both on functions and variables, makes C *way* easier to read, debug, maintain, etc and way too many professional C programmers never use it.

Comment: @TomKarzes: The term "static" is correctly used, like in the standard. There is a difference between the `static` storage class specifier and static variables (vs. e.g. automatic).

Comment: @vsoftco: You don't need to use `extern` to reference a variable in another CU. A tentative definition without final definition is actually enough.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks, edited, forgot about this (used too much with C++).

Comment: @M.M: I think Brian explianed the problem well enough ("The statement "By default it is visible only ...").

Comment: I don't think OP will benefit from using non-standard terms or oversimplifications. Better use them and explain. However, he better use a C book to learn such vital concepts.

Comment: Removed the DV. Still, I don't see any benefit from differentiating between `extern int i;` and `int i;`. Note also the latter is a _declaration_ which is also a _tentative **definition**_. As there is no other declaration or final definition until the end of the CU, it is "demoted" to a definition for the final code. (I also have to read the standard for all this formal stuff - too deep into the woods).

Comment: Not sure, but is C++ not quite similar with that?

Comment: @Olaf, I edited the answer and used all gory details regarding linkage ;) C++ has no tentative definitions, you need `extern`.

Comment: @Olaf `extern int i;` is not a definition at all, it's quite different to `int i;`

Comment: @M.M: Where did I state `extern int i;` is a _definition? They are not that different here actually, as both are declararations in the first place. But only the latter is also a tentative definition (I think I already stated that). You just cannot have a definition with `extern`.

Comment: @Olaf Not sure about C, but in C++ you can have a definition with `extern`, namely for `const` variables, which by default [have internal linkage in `C++` (not the case for C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998425/why-does-const-imply-internal-linkage-in-c-when-it-doesnt-in-c). So if you want to change the linkage, you do `extern const int i = 42;`.

Comment: @vsoftco: About `const`: That is one of the differences between the two languages anyway, as they are true constants. C does not have such a concept. But thanks for the update. I actually did not thnik much about the formal background, just use it.